# How to prove this function is increasing $\frac{e^x - x -1}{x^2}$

Tags: analysis

How to prove that the function $\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{e^x - x - 1}{x^2} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-2}}{k!}$ is increasing?

Edit for context: I was asking because this function appears in Wainwright's high dimensional statistics textbook, as part of proving a Bernstein type probability inequality for random variables that are bounded on one side.

Comment: @Andronicus $x^{2k}$ is not increasing in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) $ for every $k\in\Bbb N$ and every $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\not =0$ we have :

$$\int_0^1 v\exp(uvx)du=\frac{\exp(vx)-1}{x}$$ and
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\exp(vx)-1}{x}dv =\frac{1}{x}(\frac{\exp(vx)}{x}-v)_0^1=\frac{\exp(x)-1-x}{x^2}$$
Hence with $D=[0,1]\times [0,1]$
$$\int \int_Dv\exp(uvx)dudv= \frac{\exp(x)-1-x}{x^2}$$ and this is also true for $x=0$. Now use that the function $x\to v\exp(uvx)$ for fixed $u,v\in [0,1]$is increasing.

Comment: Wow nice! I thought that the $v$ in $v\exp(uvx)$ in the first integral should be $u$, but the final integral looks symmetric w.r.t $u$ and $v$ so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ffffffyyyyy Yes, you are true, I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

The function should be extended by continuity at $0$ with $h(0)=1/2$ and it becomes differentiable at $0$ with $h'(0)=1/6$.

For $x\ne0$, it holds
$$
h'(x)=\dfrac{(x-2)e^x+x+2}{x^3}
$$
and we can consider $g(x)=(x-2)e^x+x+2$. Then $g'(x)=(x-1)e^x+1$ and $g''(x)=xe^x$. Thus we infer that $g'$ has a minimum at $x=0$, with $g'(0)=0$. Therefore we have $g'(x)>0$ for $x\ne0$, which proves that $g$ is strictly increasing.

Since $g(0)=0$, we conclude that $g(x)<0$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

Therefore $h'(x)>0$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative
$$h’(c)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{(k+3)!}c^k$$
is clearly positive for $x>0$.
Combine two Summands
$$\frac{k+1}{(k+3)!}x^k+\frac{k+2}{(k+4)!}x^{k*1}
=\frac}(k+1)(k+4)+(k+2)x}{(k+4)!}x^k
$$where $k$ is even. This is positive at least for $x>-2$. We conclude that $ h$ is increasing on $[-2,\infty)$.

We also  have
$$h‘(x)=\frac{(e^x-1)x^2-(e^x-x-1)2x}{x^4}
=\frac{(x^2-2x)e^x+x^2+2x}{x^4}
=\frac{((x-1)^2-1)e^x+(x+1)^2-1}{x^4}$$
In which form we readily see that $h’$ is positive for $x<-2$.